# Java how can remove everything between two substring in a string

Tags: java, replace, substring

I want to remove any substring(s) in a string that begins with 'galery' and ends with 'jssdk));'

For instance, consider the following string:
  **Galery something something.... jssdk));**

I need an algorithm that removes 'something something....' and returns 'Galery jssdk));'

This is what I've done, but it does not work.

```
newsValues[1].replaceAll("Galery.*?jssdK));", "");
```

Comment: If you know it should begin with `Galery` and end with `jssdk`, why not do `String newString = "Galeryjssdk"` instead of doing any replacing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could probably be improved, I've done it fast:

```
  public static String replaceMatching(String input, String lowerBound, String upperBound{
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?"+lowerBound+"(.*?)"+upperBound+".*?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    String textToRemove = "";

    while(m.find()){
        textToRemove = m.group(1);
    }
    return input.replace(textToRemove, "");
}
```

**UPDATE** Thx for accepting the answer, but here is a smaller reviewed version:

```
 public static String replaceMatching2(String input, String lowerBound, String upperBound){
      String result = input.replaceAll("(.*?"+lowerBound + ")" + "(.*?)" + "(" + upperBound + ".*)", "$1$3");
      return result;
 }
```

The idea is pretty simple actually, split the String into 3 groups, and replace those 3 groups with the first and third, droping the second one.

Comment: Seems like you have some extra String concatenation in the updated one.  Also, you can remove the `result` variable and `return input.replaceAll...`

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, but that will remove the entire string. If you want to remove anything between `Galery` and `jssdK));`, you will have to do something like so:

`String newStr = newsValues[1].replaceAll("(Galery)(.*?)(jssdK\\)\\);)","$1$3");`

This will put the strings into groups and will then use these groups to replace the entire string. Note that in regex syntax, the `)` is a special character so it needs to be escaped.

```
String str = "GaleryABCDEFGjssdK));";
String newStr = str.replaceAll("(Galery)(.*?)(jssdK\\)\\);)","$1$3");
System.out.println(newStr);
```

This yields: `GaleryjssdK));`

I know that the solution presented by @amit is simpler, however, I thought it would be a good idea to show you a useful way in which you can use the `replaceAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution will be to replace the string with just the "edges", effectively "removing" <sup>1</sup> everything between them.

```
newsValues[1].replaceAll("Galery.*?jssdK));", "GaleryjssdK));");
```

---

1: I used `""` here because it is not exactly replacing - remember strings are immutable, so it is creating a new object, without the "removed" part.

Answer (score 0):

```
newsValues[1] = newsValues[1].substring(0,6)+newsValues.substring(newsValues[1].length()-5,newsValues[1].length())
```

This basically concatenates the "Galery" and the "jssdk" leaving or ignoring everything else. More importantantly, you can simply assign newValues[1] = "Galeryjssdk"